# Android Time&Date Picker

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any android widget that enable to pick the date and the time at the same time ? I already use the basic date picker and date picker:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html
but they are not that sexy and user friendly (I found). Do you know if a widget including both date and time exists? Thanks a lot,WW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into Android other than the widgets you have already tried -- sorry!